# Writing django validators. Do i need a own file for validators?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In the Django Manuel is an example for **Writing validators**. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/

> qoute

---

For example, here’s a validator that only allows even numbers:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
    )
```

You can add this to a model field via the field’s validators argument:

```
> from django.db import models
> 
> class MyModel(models.Model):
>     even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```

---

> qoute end

But where should i put this code?

```
 from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

    def validate_even(value):
        if value % 2 != 0:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
                params={'value': value},
        )
```

should i create a own File like **validator.py**  or should i put this in the model?

Comment: I put my project wide, reusable validators in **core/validators.py**. App level validators in **app/validators.py**. You could keep them in **models.py** or **forms.py** (or *serializers.py* if using django rest framework) if they're not many lines but my personal preference is to separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's best practice to separate the different logic components of your code as much as you can. so put **only** the code for your model in the model file and put the validator code in a separate file.